# misra 19.10 with array initialiser

Tags: c, misra

MISRA 19.10:

In the definition of a function-like macro each instance of a parameter shall be enclosed in parentheses unless it is used as the operand of # or ##.

I have a struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  SUint_t        affValueIndex;
  const SFloat_t affLoSaturation;
  const SFloat_t affHiSaturation;
  const SFloat_t affCoeffTab[SDEF_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_LEN];
  SFloat_t       affValueTab[SDEF_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_LEN];
} SAnalogFloatFilter_t;
```

Then I do:

```
#define DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_COEFF_LIST {0.0287421759f, \
                                      0.1225311874f, \
                                      0.2123775504f, \
                                      0.2726981726f, \
                                      0.2123775504f, \
                                      0.1225311874f, \
                                      0.0287421759f}

#define SMK_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_HANDLE(__name__, __coeff_list__, __hi_sat__, __low_sat__) \
SAnalogFloatFilter_t (__name__)[1] = {{0u, (__low_sat__), (__hi_sat__), __coeff_list__ , {(SFloat_t)0,}}}

static SMK_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_HANDLE(CurrMonFilter,
                                      DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_COEFF_LIST,
                                      (SFloat_t)DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_HI_SAT,
                                      (SFloat_t)DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_LO_SAT);
```

The problem is that the __ coeff_list __ parameter cannot have a parenthesis as it then expands to ({...}) (an array initialilser), to which the gcc complains:

```
foo.c:45:9: error: statement-expressions are not allowed outside functions nor in template-argument lists
```

Is there a clever way to keep the MISRA 19.10 check AND have an array initialiser in the SMK_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_HANDLE macro?

Comment: Another stupid rule that misses a lot of exceptions.

Comment: I think escaping newlines within your definition of `DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_COEFF_LIST` might be a good thing...

Comment: Insert a # operator in the macro definition that discards the argument.

Comment: @twalberg Sorry, those are actually there, but got lost when stripping some comments.

Comment: @n.m. Could you please elaborate?  How would stringify an argument help me?

Comment: "... unless it is used as the operand of # or ##."

Comment: @n.m. I know, but I don't see how stringifying or concatinating the arguments helps me.  Perhaps you could provide a concrete example?  I need the DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_COEFF_LIST to be properly expanded.

Comment: I think the MISRA-checker is trying to tell you that this macro-mess needs to get rewritten, since it is unreadable and unsafe. You won't manage to make this MISRA-C compatible. In particular, you should heed rule 19.7: "A function should be used in preference of a function-like macro". Don't try to dodge the rules. Instead, write readable code.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for your input.  While I don't outright disagree with you, the full story is a bit more complicated.  First of all, this is a static instantiation of a struct, hence the #19.7 is not really helpful here.  Secondly, we also have a lot of auto-generated code where macros help unifying the auto-generated and the manual code.

In this particular application it helps to hide the implementation and only expose the relevant part of the structure.

Comment: `SMK_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_HANDLE` is a function-like macro, no matter what purpose you use it for. If you want to hide the implementation, you should consider using opaque/incomplete type instead. It will make the code far more readable and safe.

Comment: @Lundin I appreciate your comments, but they don't answer the question.  There are multiple constraints here.  It's next to impossible to go into all the design issues which have lead to the current implementation.  This is a micro controller and memory is *tight*.  We use function like macros all over the place, and while I know it is frown upon, it has proven useful (with the current constraints).  Hence have we added an exception for #19.7.  I might have seen me blind on the problem, but I don't see how opaque types can be used here without a major redesign and increased bloat.

Comment: @FrodeTennebo I work pretty much exclusively with small, constrained micro-controller applications. That's no excuse for using macros such as these. Unless perhaps your compiler is bad at optimizing and inlining. (You are using float, so memory can't be -that- tight.) Indeed opaque types would mean a major re-design, but no increased memory consumption. The bottom line is that the whole purpose of MISRA is to stop crap code from entering mission-critical systems. If you have a case such as "my program needs to be crap, because...", then you should probably skip MISRA for the whole project.

Comment: @Lundin There is no time for a major re-design, this is a somewhat legacy code base which I'm trying to clean up.  MISRA 19.7 is advisory and you can't possibly claim that adding exceptions for advisory rules generally make the code crappy?  19.10 is just for the case when 19.7 is exempted.  Adding setters/getters and calling those does in my experience result in more code being generated, especially compared to a static initialisation.  I hear what you are saying, I just don't see how I can do what you are suggesting withing the constraints I'm working with.

Comment: @FrodeTennebo What I meant was that if you have to make a deviation from 19.10, you will probably have to make a whole lot of other deviations as well. And in the end, the claim for MISRA compliance will be some sort of polished lie. Better then to drop MISRA completely, it is not very suitable to use for old legacy code. Which again is one of the purposes: if you have some old, dangerous code, you cannot easily turn it MISRA-compliant without the major re-design.

Comment: @Lundin I never intended to make a deviation from #19.10, only from #19.7.

The problem seems to be that MISRA #19.10 expects that parentheses around all arguments in function-like macros results in syntactically correct C. This is clearly not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles for me:

```
typedef int SUint_t;
typedef float SFloat_t;

#define SDEF_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_LEN 8

typedef struct
{
  SUint_t        affValueIndex;
  const SFloat_t affLoSaturation;
  const SFloat_t affHiSaturation;
  const SFloat_t affCoeffTab[SDEF_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_LEN];
  SFloat_t       affValueTab[SDEF_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_LEN];
} SAnalogFloatFilter_t;

#define DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_COEFF_LIST (const SFloat_t[SDEF_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_LEN]) \
                                     {0.0287421759f, \
                                      0.1225311874f, \
                                      0.2123775504f, \
                                      0.2726981726f, \
                                      0.2123775504f, \
                                      0.1225311874f, \
                                      0.0287421759f}

#define SMK_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_HANDLE(__name__, __coeff_list__, __hi_sat__, __low_sat__) \
SAnalogFloatFilter_t (__name__)[1] = {{0u, (__low_sat__), (__hi_sat__), (__coeff_list__) , {(SFloat_t)0,}}}

#define DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_HI_SAT 0.0f
#define DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_LO_SAT 0.0f

static SMK_ANALOG_FLOAT_FILTER_HANDLE(CurrMonFilter,
                                      DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_COEFF_LIST,
                                      (SFloat_t)DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_HI_SAT,
                                      (SFloat_t)DEF_ANALOG_FILTER_LO_SAT);
```

Tested on Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS with commands:

```
gcc-4.6 -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

and

```
gcc-4.8 -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't fly. gcc reports: "error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer"

Besides, won't that translate to a const double*?

Comment: Which system, compiler and version do you have? On Linux Mint 13.10 with g++ 4.8 it works.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: The problem was that I typed it as double not SFloat_t. And sorry I tested it with gcc 4.8 not g++.

Comment: Great answer.  However, it appears that gcc compiles this, but not g++ (C++ is used for Google test framework).  Also, the target compiler, GHS Multi, balks on this with "cast to type "const SFloat_t [7]" is not allowed".

Comment: Beside the mistyping: Don't compile C files with a C++ compiler, because both languages are incompatible at many points. Please verify, that the Greenhill compiler is ISO C compliant. I'm not sure of that.

Comment: I can get around the problem with g++.

GHS has a strict ISO C mode which complains "a value of type "const SFloat_t *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const SFloat_t""

If I compile with the GNU compatibility mode it works, i.e. it seems to be some implicit type casting going on in 'GNU mode'?

Comment: The problem is the c standard. Section 6.7.8/4: "All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals." But it is nowhere defined, that a const-qualified expression is not a constant expression. gcc extends the specification there. Using gcc with -std=c99 it will raise an error. I think pedantic compilers are accepting only the braced list as constant expression and therefore it is impossible to fulfil the MISRA rule there.